# Create and update with checkboxes and simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, simple-form

I am trying to do something basic but for some reason that's not working and not returning me any errors.

I have a User model and a ManualBill model.

The Manual Bill belongs to a User (I can select who paid it when I create it and it belongs to this User).
But then, once the Manual Bill is created, I also want to be able to add "manual_bills_payers", who are the ones who did not pay the bill but have to refund it.
In the end, that makes my models look like this:

```
class ManualBill < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to  :flat
  belongs_to  :user
  has_many :manual_bill_payers
  has_many :users, through: :manual_bill_payers
end
```

And

```
class ManualBillPayer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :manual_bill
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I've created an update form for the ManualBill, in which I am going to select several users (who are going to be manual_bill_payers) with checkboxes (I am in  a loop which is why I called the manual_bill "bill" here.

```
  <%= simple_form_for [@flat, bill] do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
      <%= f.association :manual_bill_payers, as: :check_boxes, 
       :label_method => 
       lambda { |owner| "#{owner.email}" },collection: User.all, 
       input_html: {class: "input- 
       bar-settings"} %>
    <%= f.submit 'Add payers', class: "btn-form" %>
  <% end %>
```

I am really confused of what to do here. 
What I want to do is basically CREATE several new manual_bill_payers when updating the manual_bill by selecting users who are in my flat (all the Users of the db in the exemple above). I also want to be able to remove them by unchecking the boxes.

I've basically tried everything... from changing the models to put "has_and_belongs_to_many" instead of the "through" association, to changing the :manual_bill_payers into :users in the simple_form.

Most of the time the update goes through (no errors and redirect me to the show page) but I still get an empty array when I do ManualBillPayer.all or when I check my manual_bill.manual_bill_payers.

My update method here just in case

```
 def update
   @manual_bill = ManualBill.find(params[:id])
    authorize @manual_bill
    if @manual_bill.update(manual_bill_params)
      redirect_to flatshare_path(@manual_bill.flat)
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
 end

 def manual_bill_params
   params.require(:manual_bill).permit(:manual_bill_payer_id)
 end
```

I don't have any create method in this controller because the manual_bill is created somewhere else, which is why the last method is pretty empty

Where am I wrong? Is there something I am completely minsunderstanding?

I've put a raise in the update to check the params

```
 {"utf8"=>"✓",
   "_method"=>"patch",
   "authenticity_token"=>"280izDKna4QWfr0OhZJW6u/
  UWcqlxo56yR17fBDX4QFKhNG94mYqbBLPuq+ifo3mNIV10GFk1RK7Hr5AnmosOA==",
  "manual_bill"=>{"manual_bill_payer_ids"=>["", "1", "35", "34"]},
  "commit"=>"Add payers",
  "flatshare_id"=>"15",
  "id"=>"15"}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Update your question with the params that appear in the server log when you submit the form

Comment: Hello! I've put a raise in the update to show the params, is it ok? Otherwise I'll copy and paste my terminal but that's super long and messy so I thought the raise would be clearer?

Comment: I've done that ealier and saw that there is an empty string in my manual_bill_payer_ids, but I have absolutely no idea where it comes from!

Comment: @Pavan  for some reason I can't find your answer anymore, but it works with :users (and create an instance of manual_bill_payer). Thanks so much!!! I've been stuck on that for ages :)